# Return from long running Task to suspended/terminated app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have an app that needs to run a long task in the background. In the meantime, a user is expected to go about his business using other apps. In the case of a windows store app - that might mean that the app will be suspended/terminated.

I thought of dealing with the actual long running task by running it in a separate thread by `Task.Run`. But that raises the problem of returning the result to the UI.

1. If the app is suspended - how does a Task resume the app?
2. If the app is terminated - that's obviously a problem - I have to
   prevent that.

So - Are Windows Store Apps just not suitable for any such apps? Or is there some way around this suspend/terminate problem?

Comment: You'll need a background task not a thread in the main app (which can be suspended). Details will depend on what your background task needs to do. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299103.aspx

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT Thanks. But background tasks are very limited in how much cpu time they can consume, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

> How does a Task resume the app?

The task continues to run from where it was suspended.

> If the app is terminated - that's obviously a problem - I have to
>   prevent that.

You can't prevent app termination, you just need to adapt it, otherwise, it's indeed a problem.

Your task needs to be aware of the app life cycle. Instead of just running your code by Task.Run you should wrap your code into a class to handle the suspend and terminate events. It means your task should be pausable and also needs to be able to persist its state in order to handle app termination.

Maybe this pseudo-code gives you an idea:

```
class LongRunningTask {
    private void LongRunningJob() {
        // Do some long running job
        // Implement cancellation/pause token
    }        
    public async Task StartAsync(IState state) {
        // Load previous state
        // Start LongRunningJob()
    }
    public async Task<IState> SuspendAsync() {
        // Stop LongRunningJob() using a token
        // Return current state, in case of termination
    }
    public async Task ResumeAsync() {
       // Resume LongRunningJob using a token
    }
}
```

and in the App:

```
private async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) {
    // Check launch reason first
    // Read state from the disk
    await longRunningTask.StartAsyc(state);        
}
private async void OnResuming(object sender, object e) {
    await longRunningTask.ResumeAsync();        
}
private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e) {
    await longRunningTask.SuspendAsync();     
}
```

I know it doesn't look a clean approach at all, but considering the fact that the app cannot disallow it's life cycle, I think there is no clean way do to that.

Edit: Depending on what your code is doing, you may not need to care about the suspension since the code continues to run automatically after resuming but you obviously need to take care of app termination.